# CSS Won't Display Background Image?

Tags: css

I'm really confused as to what i'm doing wrong here. The Background Image won't show up.
CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("images/alfredo_dover.jfif");
}
```

[image: My Folder Here]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Answer depends on where the specification for body is located. When in an external CSS file inside folder css, the URL should be `url("../images/alfredo_dover.jfif");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solve and make you sure give the height.

```
background-image: url("../images/alfredo_dover.jfif");
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to give it a `background-size: cover` and give the html and body elements a height of 100%. You can also give it a `background-position: center` if you want to center the image.

Also, you might want to try a `./` in front of your path, in case the base url is being rewritten by the base href tag:

`enter code here`background-image: url("./images/alfredo_dover.jfif");

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

```css
html,body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-image: url("https://placekitten.com/400/400");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: When you remove `height: 100%` it works fine

Comment: @Gerard it actually doesn't, what you are seeing is the `background-repeat: repeat` rule tiling the image.